How to identify a GUID of a corrupted Bitlocker disk in order to find the corresponding Bitlocker recovery key?
I have a situation where I have access to a huge list of Bitlocker recovery keys but only the combination of the identifier (GUID) and recovery key are available. However the disk in question is corrupted and I don't know which identifier (GUID) belongs to this particular disk.
The disk in question likely has a corrupted partition table. A wiping tool had accidentally wiped this 5TB disk for a few minutes. Likely the beginning of the disk. The disk is physically fine. No partition are recognized in diskpart and the Windows Disk Management tool prompts to initialize the disk as MBR or GPT. More background in this question: How to properly determine if an Bitlocker encrypted disk has a corrupted partition table?
How would I identify the GUID of this disk in order to find the proper Bitlocker recovery key for it?

I don't know why this question is migrated and downvoted without comments but I disagree with both actions. This is a forensics question that belongs to the site I originally posted it on.
